# apply CSS style to element containing certain elements?

Tags: css

I found there is no official parent selector, but there are pseudo-classes like :has, so I was wondering how one would go about applying CSS to the following kind of paragraph:

```
<p><em><a href="#_ftnref11" name="_ftn11">[11]</a>&nbsp;Source Text</em></p>
```

I'd need to apply CSS to this type of paragraph, which is one in a list of several, and the only thing they have in common (besides the structure) is the '_ftn' part of the name attribute. Unfortunately, these paragraphs are also not wrapped in another element I could build the CSS on - that's how it comes out of a plugin...

Thanks for any inputs from you CSS gurus!

Comment: What is your actual HTML and CSS? What is your desired result? Probably it may be achieved without targeting the parent.

Answer (score 1):

The `:has()` CSS selector is currently not supported by any browser ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)).

However, if you want to target anchor elements which are placed within a `p > em` tag, you can do something like this:

Note the [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) `[name^="_ftn"]` on the `a` element.

```css
p em a[name^="_ftn"] {
  color: green;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<p><em><a href="#_ftnref11" name="_ftn11">[11]</a>&nbsp;Source Text</em></p>
```